# ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished after switching to mysql from sqlite3

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I recently switched my rails database over from sqlite3 to mysql, and since doing it I've had a ConnectionNotEstablished error when trying to access my server.

Here is the full stack trace of the error.

```
ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished (ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished):
  activerecord (3.2.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:404:in `retrieve_connection'
  activerecord (3.2.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:170:in `retrieve_connection'
  activerecord (3.2.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:144:in `connection'
  activerecord (3.2.8) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:67:in `rescue in call'
  activerecord (3.2.8) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:61:in `call'
  activerecord (3.2.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:473:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
  activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__318842653__call__302530175__callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
  activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
  railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
  railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call' 
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'
  railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
  railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
  /home/aaron/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /home/aaron/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /home/aaron/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
```

The connection with the database seems to be working fine.  I can run db:migrate and it runs fine, as well as Rails console, and I can access the data and everything just fine.
I've noticed that when I boot up, the error works slightly different depending on the environment.  It seems to run fine in test.   In development, it throws the error when I visit the page in the browser, and in production it throws the error when I boot it up.

The problem seems pretty much identical to what was presented here:
[Rails and MySQL - ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished in production environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9142978/rails-and-mysql-activerecordconnectionnotestablished-in-production-environme),
but none of the answers worked for me.

I have all the code pushed up here: https://github.com/Aaronneyer/aaronneyer.com

Comment: Add .sass-cache to your .gitignore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Still not sure what was the exact cause of this, but I was able to solve it by removing the newrelic gem, which was no longer being used anyways.

Comment: I spent literally hours and hours of debugging very weird ActiveRecord connection errors of different kinds in Rake cron jobs (with PostgreSQL), and wanted to say thank you since your comment solved my issue. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Howdy - I work for New Relic and wanted to chime in that we've addressed the root cause of this issue in version 3.6.4 of the newrelic_rpm gem. Sorry for the headache it caused you!

Answer (score 0):

You have both socket and host setup. Pick one, might solve your issue.

Comment: Nope, tried with just socket and just host.  Same thing happened for each case.