# "ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished" error after I switched from SQLite to Postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, rubygems

I recently switched my rails database over from sqlite3 to Postgres, and since then I've had a ConnectionNotEstablished error when trying to run my server. Is anyone familiar with this bug?

Here is the full stack trace of the error.

```
        Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
        Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
):

activerecord (7.0.4) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:87:in `rescue in new_client'
activerecord (7.0.4) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:77:in `new_client'
activerecord (7.0.4) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:37:in `postgresql_connection'
activerecord (7.0.4) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:656:in `public_send'
activerecord (7.0.4) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:656:in `new_connection'
activerecord (7.0.4) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:700:in `checkout_new_connection'
activerecord (7.0.4) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:679:in `try_to_checkout_new_connection'
activerecord (7.0.4) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:640:in `acquire_connection'
activerecord (7.0.4) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:341:in `checkout'
activerecord (7.0.4) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:181:in `connection'
activerecord (7.0.4) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_handler.rb:211:in `retrieve_connection'
activerecord (7.0.4) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:313:in `retrieve_connection'
activerecord (7.0.4) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:280:in `connection'
activerecord (7.0.4) lib/active_record/migration.rb:613:in `connection'
activerecord (7.0.4) lib/active_record/migration.rb:608:in `build_watcher'
activerecord (7.0.4) lib/active_record/migration.rb:590:in `block in call'
activerecord (7.0.4) lib/active_record/migration.rb:589:in `synchronize'
activerecord (7.0.4) lib/active_record/migration.rb:589:in `call'
actionpack (7.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `block in call'
activesupport (7.0.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:99:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (7.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in `call'
actionpack (7.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (7.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/actionable_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (7.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:28:in `call'
web-console (4.2.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:132:in `call_app'
web-console (4.2.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
web-console (4.2.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:17:in `catch'
web-console (4.2.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (7.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:26:in `call'
railties (7.0.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:40:in `call_app'
railties (7.0.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:25:in `block in call'
activesupport (7.0.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:99:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (7.0.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:37:in `tagged'
activesupport (7.0.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:99:in `tagged'
railties (7.0.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:25:in `call'
sprockets-rails (3.4.2) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (7.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:93:in `call'
actionpack (7.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:26:in `call'
rack (2.2.4) lib/rack/method_override.rb:24:in `call'
rack (2.2.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
activesupport (7.0.4) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:29:in `call'
actionpack (7.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/server_timing.rb:61:in `block in call'
actionpack (7.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/server_timing.rb:26:in `collect_events'
actionpack (7.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/server_timing.rb:60:in `call'
actionpack (7.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (7.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:23:in `call'
rack (2.2.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:110:in `call'
actionpack (7.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/host_authorization.rb:137:in `call'
railties (7.0.4) lib/rails/engine.rb:530:in `call'
puma (5.6.5) lib/puma/configuration.rb:252:in `call'
puma (5.6.5) lib/puma/request.rb:77:in `block in handle_request'
puma (5.6.5) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:340:in `with_force_shutdown'
puma (5.6.5) lib/puma/request.rb:76:in `handle_request'
puma (5.6.5) lib/puma/server.rb:443:in `process_client'
puma (5.6.5) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:147:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

// My Gem file

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby "2.7.6"

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem "rails", github: "rails/rails", branch: "main"
gem "rails", "~> 7.0.4"

# The original asset pipeline for Rails [https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails]
gem "sprockets-rails"

# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem "pg"
gem "hirb"
# Use the Puma web server [https://github.com/puma/puma]
gem "puma", "~> 5.0"

# Use JavaScript with ESM import maps [https://github.com/rails/importmap-rails]
gem "importmap-rails"

# Hotwire's SPA-like page accelerator [https://turbo.hotwired.dev]
gem "turbo-rails"

# Hotwire's modest JavaScript framework [https://stimulus.hotwired.dev]
gem "stimulus-rails"

# Build JSON APIs with ease [https://github.com/rails/jbuilder]
gem "jbuilder"

# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem "redis", "~> 4.0"

# Use Kredis to get higher-level data types in Redis [https://github.com/rails/kredis]
# gem "kredis"

# Use Active Model has_secure_password [https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_model_basics.html#securepassword]
gem "bcrypt", "~> 3.1.7"

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem "tzinfo-data", platforms: %i[ mingw mswin x64_mingw jruby ]

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem "bootsnap", require: false

# Use Sass to process CSS
# gem "sassc-rails"

# Use Active Storage variants [https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#transforming-images]
# gem "image_processing", "~> 1.2"

group :development, :test do
  # See https://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#debugging-with-the-debug-gem
  gem "debug", platforms: %i[ mri mingw x64_mingw ]
end

group :development do
  # Use console on exceptions pages [https://github.com/rails/web-console]
  gem "web-console"

  # Add speed badges [https://github.com/MiniProfiler/rack-mini-profiler]
  # gem "rack-mini-profiler"

  # Speed up commands on slow machines / big apps [https://github.com/rails/spring]
  # gem "spring"
end

group :test do
  # Use system testing [https://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#system-testing]
  gem "capybara"
  gem "selenium-webdriver"
  gem "webdrivers"
end
```

```
//database.yml
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  # For details on connection pooling, see Rails configuration guide
  # https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#database-pooling
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>

development:
  <<: *default
  database: DojoSecrets_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: DojoSecrets_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: DojoSecrets_production
  username: DojoSecrets
  password: <%= ENV["DOJOSECRETS_DATABASE_PASSWORD"] %>
```

If there's any other files that might be helpful to see please let me know. Also, I have referenced this post: "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12084368/activerecordconnectionnotestablished-after-switching-to-mysql-from-sqlite3" however, my Gemfile does not have the gem that it states was causing its issue.

Comment: The error message tells that there is no PostgreSQL running on localhost. That makes sense because you cannot run PostgreSQL on the same dyno as a web application. How did you configure your database.yml? How did you install the database or the database addon? Did you double check that the database credentials and URL are available in the environment variables?

Comment: database.yml file is added. I was going to try to run the server locally like sqlite3. I just ran the command: rails new DojoSecrets --database=postgresql --skip-test-unit
to switch to PostgreSQL.

Comment: Did you install a PostgreSQL addon on Heroku? https://elements.heroku.com/addons/heroku-postgresql

Comment: I figured it out, I hadn't downloaded but once I did it worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

```
Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
        Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
```

it says that your rails app can't connect to the psql server, probably because it's not turned on. How to turn it on/check the status depends on your setup (whether you're using docker or a local instance, a remote instance)